# App dose not work on the older version of android 2.2 because a large database file

Tags: android

I have a big database file in the project in the last version of android everything working fine but in the older i an error that tht database is too big :Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX

I search on the web but i did not find any answer

I will appreciate help thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please read below for the possible solution (worked for me).

I too was unable to run my app on versions older than 2.3.3 but when I renamed my .html file (which was 4MB due to Web SQL commands) to .jet (or for that matter any already-compressed extension as mentioned in [enter link description here](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/)), it worked fine on 2.1 update1 and 2.2 also.

The problem was Android versions older to 2.3.3 were trying to compress all files more than 1MB in size in the /assets/ folder. So, I renamed it to already-compressed extension so that the Android does not try to compress it again. Though I am not aware of Android programming, I think that is what is happening after reading the above and few other links online.